# Google Cloud Messaging Push Notification: PushNotification

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an ionic application with Google Cloud Messaging Push Notification with Visual Studio. First I add phonegap-plugin-push from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push and insert my senderID which is Project number from Google Cloud Messaging API. Next, I add following code.

```
      var push = PushNotification.init({
         "android" : {
          "senderID" : "9XX5XXX346XX"// This is your project number which you've created on Google Developers Console
         },
         "ios" : {},
         "windows" : {}
        });

   push.on('registration', function(data) {
    //data.registrationId
    //send this token on server

   });
   push.on('notification', function(data) {
    if (data.sound) {// play specific sound on notification received(When app running)
     var snd = new Media('file:///android_asset/www/sound/' + data.sound);
     snd.play();
    }

    if (!data.additionalData.foreground) {
     // app is NOT RUNNING and new notification is RECEIVED

    } else {
     // app is RUNNING and new notification is RECEIVED
    }
   });

   push.on('error', function(e) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    // e.message
   });
```

When I run my application in emulator and android device. It comes with eror PushNotification.init. May I know why?

Comment: Please paste complete error log.

Comment: @HardikVaghani My error is PushNotification.init is undefined. But I had add phonegap-plugin-push into my project.

Comment: may be plugins isn't installed properly thats why its not getting reference to `PushNotification` as a result its undefined.

Comment: @HardikVaghani  I am pretty sure plugin is installed properly by   cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push. May be I have to do some configuration to get PushNotification.

Comment: In your config.xml did you replaced widgetId with your appId??

Comment: @AkashKR Is replace with my Ionic AppID or GCM Project Number?

Comment: Replace with ionic appId

Comment: @AkashKR After I replace my widget id with my ionic id. widget id="6$5###16". It even worst, compile with error now.

Comment: May be you have done something wrong. Let me share you a link

Comment: @AkashKR Ok, can you send me the link. Actually I am following tutorial from http://ionicguru.blogspot.my/2015/12/android-push-notification-via-php.html

Comment: Check this out https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/

Comment: @AkashKR Ok, thanks. It worked for me